# lwc looping till a certain number in html

Tags: lightning-web-components, loop, html-template-directives

In lwc for looping through data we have

```
<template for:each={contacts} for:item="val">
</template>
```

If i have a variable where in a number is stored, say for example 4. How do i run the loop 4 times in html, inside which i'm trying to create some dynamic elements.

Answer (score 4):

Create an array of 4 items in the JavaScript controller (that is run the loop up to the number there) and reference that much like contacts in your HTML example.

Comment: Yes i thought about that, but no other way to directly achieve it in html ?

Comment: Don’t think so. LWC and maybe web components in general (intentionally) try to keep expressions out of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have `for:` loops in LWC, however if you use child components you can sort of do what you want based on index.

Step 1. Define a child component

js

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ChildComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api index;

    get shouldDisplay() {
        return this.index <= 4;
    }
}
```

html

```
<template>
    <div if:true={shouldDisplay}>
       whatever we want here
    </div>
</template>
```

Step 2. Use child component in our loop in the parent component

```
<template for:each={contacts} for:item="val" for:index="idx">
    <c-child-component index={idx}></c-child-component>
</template>
```

(you can also pass along your actual object etc. any other data from `val` obviously)

This will not stop the loop executing but the items with index > 4 won't render.